# Olympus Camera Kit: App exits when it draws face detection frame on the live view

Tags: ios, objective-c, olympus-air, olympus-camerakit

I'm working on the capture program for Olympus Air A01 that updates face detection result on the live view image in real time. The face detection result is acquired from Camera Kit but my app exits when a face is detected. My program updates live view image in `didUpdateLiveView` and passes data to `drawFaceFrame:cameraFrame:`

The version of Olympus Camera Kit is 1.1.0.

```
@interface ViewController() <OLYCameraLiveViewDelegate>
//OLYCamera Class
@property (weak, nonatomic) OLYCamera *camera;

//For live view
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *liveView; 

//8 UIViews for face detection frame
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIView) NSArray *faceViews; 
@end

- (void)camera:(OLYCamera *)camera didUpdateLiveView:(NSData *)data metadata:(NSDictionary *)metadata
{
    //UPDATE LIVE VIEW IMAGE HERE

        CGRect frame = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(self.liveView.image.size, self.liveView.frame); 
        [self drawFaceFrame:camera.detectedHumanFaces cameraFrame:frame];
    }
}

//Draw face detection frame
- (void)drawFaceFrame:(NSDictionary *)faces cameraFrame:(CGRect)frame
{    
    const CGFloat ratioW = cameraFrame.size.width / self.imageView.image.size.width;
        const CGFloat ratioH = cameraFrame.size.height / self.imageView.image.size.height;

        unsigned int i = 0;
        for ( ; detectedHumanFaces && i < detectedHumanFaces.count ; ++i)
        {
        NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
            NSValue *value = detectedHumanFaces[key];
            CGRect rect = [value CGRectValue]; 
            CGRect rectInImage = OLYCameraConvertRectOnViewfinderIntoLiveImage(rect, self.imageView.image); 
        CGRect rectInView = rectInImage;
        rectInView.origin.x *= ratioW; 
        rectInView.origin.y *= ratioH;
        rectInView.origin.x += cameraFrame.origin.x;
        rectInView.origin.y += cameraFrame.origin.y;
        rectInView.size.width *= ratioW;
        rectInView.size.height *= ratioH;

        if (i < self.faceViews.count)
        {
            UIView *faceView = [self.faceViews objectAtIndex:i];
            CALayer *layer = [faceView layer];
            [layer setBorderColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColor];

            faceView.frame = rectInView;
            faceView.hidden = NO;
        }
    }

    // Hide unused frames
    for ( ; i < [self.faceViews count] ; ++i) 
    {
        UIView *faceView = [self.faceViews objectAtIndex:i];
        faceView.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be two issues:

1. Your app draws every face detection frame even if the camera does not detect any faces.
2. Camera Kit may update `detectedHumanFaces` within the time your app calculates coordinates of the frames and the time your app draws the frames.

The first point is not critical, but not so good. I recommend Key-value Observation (KVO) technique, which is called only when the camera detects a face.

KVO is effective to address the second issue.  You can copy `detectedHumanFaces` in the method called by observer. `detectedHumanFacesValueDidChange` method is called by observer in the code below.

```
@interface ViewController () <OLYCameraLiveViewDelegate>
//OLYCamera Class
@property (weak, nonatomic) OLYCamera *camera;
//For face detection frames
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIView) NSArray *detectedHumanFaceViews;
@end

/// Called by observer when Camera Kit update detectedHumanFaces property.
- (void)detectedHumanFacesValueDidChange {

    // Save live view image and detected face information
    // to make consistent with the number of faces and their coordinates when app updates face detection frame.
    UIImage *image = self.imageView.image;
    NSDictionary *detectedHumanFaces = camera.detectedHumanFaces;
    if (image == nil || detectedHumanFaces == nil) {
        // Show face detection frame only if a live view image and detected face information are confirmed.
        for (UIView *detectedHumanFaceView in self.detectedHumanFaceViews) {
            detectedHumanFaceView.hidden = YES;
        }
        return;
    }
    for (NSInteger index = 0; index < self.detectedHumanFaceViews.count; index++) {
        // Confirm detected face information corresponding to the view for face detection frame.
        // The camera detects eight faces at the maximum.
        UIView *detectedHumanFaceView = self.detectedHumanFaceViews[index];
        NSString *faceKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", index];
        NSValue *faceValue = detectedHumanFaces[faceKey];
        if (!faceValue) {
            detectedHumanFaceView.hidden = YES;
            continue;
        }
        // Decide coordinates of the face detection frame on the screen  
        CGRect imageRect = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(image.size, self.imageView.bounds);
        CGFloat xRatio = imageRect.size.width / image.size.width;
        CGFloat yRatio = imageRect.size.height / image.size.height;
        CGRect faceRect = OLYCameraConvertRectOnViewfinderIntoLiveImage([faceValue CGRectValue], image);
        CGFloat x = faceRect.origin.x * xRatio + imageRect.origin.x;
        CGFloat y = faceRect.origin.y * yRatio + imageRect.origin.y;
        CGFloat w = faceRect.size.width * xRatio;
        CGFloat h = faceRect.size.height * yRatio;
        CGRect viewRect = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);
        // Draw face detection frame.
        detectedHumanFaceView.frame = viewRect;
        detectedHumanFaceView.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```